# Ошибка в синтаксисе SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такой код:

```
  create table CHECK(CHECK_CODE int PRIMARY KEY, DATA datetime not null, SUM Decimal(64,30) not null,NUMBER_CASHBOX int not null,CASHIER varchar(255) not null,CALCULATION_FORM varchar(255) not null,tovar_id int, FOREIGN KEY (tovar_id) REFERENCES PRODUCT(PRODUCT_CODE) );
```

Выдаёт ошибку: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHECK(CHECK_CODE int PRIMARY KEY, DATA datetime not null, SUM Decimal(64,30) not' at line 1

Так и не понял, почему, сверял с предыдущими таблицами, всё работало,подскажите что не так использую

Comment: Экранируйте все ключевые слова символами ` наверное?

Comment: CREATE TABLE  `CHECK`  , когда взял его в "одинарные кавычки" заработал, но вопрос почему в остальных таблицах такой ошибки не выдавало остаётся открытым.

Comment: @Dreams возможно это связано с ключевыми словами.

Comment: точно, вы правы, даже не подумал об этом, спасибо, вопрос закрыт!